# iOS AFNetworking: Multiple WiFi Networks

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Have a quick question on AFNetworking (2.0) Reachability Manager.

I have the code (iOS-Objective C) for checking the status of WiFi via Reachability Manager and all works fine-Good.

What happens when I have turned "ON" multiple WiFi networks in my device? 
How does AFNetworking determine if WiFi is down or active?

If i am not wrong, when one WiFi network goes down, the other WiFi network will automatically be active right - i'm i making sense?

And finally, is it possible to have "AFNetworking" monitor for a specific "WiFi" network by a "WiFi Network Name" or something like that.

Cheers

Comment: what do you mean with "active"? Do you want to check if there's access to the internet, regardless of whether you're connected to wifi or not?

Comment: What i actually meant by "Active" was - "WiFi Connectivity". Not the access to internet.